# Want a redirection for a specific URl. so logged out users cannot be access the page directly. i amm working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

For Example i have this "http://localhost/traffictack/woorank/" URL and i want that it can be only access by the logged in user. if any other user directly access to this url it redirected to home page:

```
  if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   { 
    redirect('login');
   }
```

Comment: Ok. Great. Looks like you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (empty($this->session->userdata('logged_in')))
{ 
    redirect('login'); # use not logged in
}
else{
    redirect('home'); # logged user
}
```

Or else

**In Controller**

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();

}

function is_logged_in() {
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if ((!isset($is_logged_in))) {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: So where i will define this condition in a controller? and then where that function will be called? @abdulla

Comment: you can use in every controller method

Comment: @TechLeadzWPTeam try second method

Comment: and how it will be check for this URL  http://localhost/traffictack/woorank/
i just want to protect this url from non logged in users. if user is not logged in and directly access this url it will be redirected to home page that's it.

Comment: I have used this function but its not working:
        public function redirect() {
        $result = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);
        if ($this->uri->segment(1) == "woorank" && !$result) {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

Comment: are you setting session at loging user??

Comment: foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {
                //add all data to session
                $newdata = array(
                    'user_id' => $rows->id,
                    'user_name' => $rows->username,
                    'user_email' => $rows->email,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return true;
        }

Comment: So check is `logged_in` withour URI segment